# Execution failed for task 'app:process:DebugResources'

Tags: android

So out of the blue I've ran into this problem. This is the Gradle Build console output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxvfR.png

I've checked some posts online (mostly SO). So far I've changed the buildToolsVersion (which it doesn't let me be lower than 25.0.0), did Clean Builds, Restarts, checked all XML files for problems.

Nothing solved it. Also I didn't find anything about the first few errors ("No resourse matches..."). I tried to change those files to delete those lines but 1)"They're not part of the project" 2)If I change in anyway there's another error.

I've also returned to previous builds of my code, which worked and somehow now they all show the same errors.

Can you point me in the right direction? I want to understand what's wrong and how can I solve this?

**[UPDATE]**

Here's the code for `res\layout\abc_list_menu_item_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall">

<!-- Icon will be inserted here. -->

<!-- The title and summary have some gap between them, and this 'group' should be centered vertically. -->
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:layout_marginRight="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:duplicateParentState="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scale"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shortcut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Checkbox, and/or radio button will be inserted here. -->
```

And this one's for `res\layout\abc_popup_menu_item_layout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:minWidth="196dip"
    style="@style/RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenuItem">

<!-- Icon will be inserted here. -->

<!-- The title and summary have some gap between them, and this 'group' should be centered vertically. -->
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        style="@style/RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenuItem.InternalGroup">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scale"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            style="@style/RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenuItem.Text" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shortcut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            style="@style/RtlOverlay.Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenuItem.Text" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/submenuarrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

<!-- Checkbox, and/or radio button will be inserted here. -->
```

The difference of these two to the `res\merged\debug\SAME_NAME` is none other than an error on the line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`saying URI is not registered. Since both of these files were created automatically  I have no idea what's going on. I've searched this last "URI not registered" error but all the solutions presented are so different and seem so specific to one's project that they don't seem to apply here. I tried using Build Variant "release" and then changing it back but nothing happened again.

Comment: Can you post the file "res/layout/abc_list_menu_item_layout.xml".  Also, do you have more than one version of that file (maybe in different "res/layout-?" directories?

It appears that the layout is referencing a view id that has not been defined.

Comment: @AndroidGuy Thanks for the prompt response. I already edited the question to show the code and explain a little bit further what I was experiencing. There are no duplicates other than now after using the Build Variant "release". I noticed that two of the files are in build-cache. If I invalidate it and restart should it work? Cheers!

Comment: answering to myself, the invalidate/restart cache does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This happens out of the blue for me as well.  I'm paying attention as to why that happened, but the solution is to clear the build cache.
To execute the task, select View > Tool Windows > Terminal from the menu bar and use one of the following commands:

For Windows:

```
 gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

For Mac or Linux:

```
 ./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

For future reference and related options, check out this link:
[Clear the build cache](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-cache.html#clear_the_build_cache)

Comment: Worked for me. Not sure how the rename command managed to mess up my system so bad. This is why you never ever use names like "title" I had done everything, including reinstillng all my repos and the Android SDK. Didn't think I needed to clear gradle explicitly (though I did blow out the wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

Now, I finally got this to work but have simply no idea why or how it started working. So I had this ListView in one of my layouts and I wanted to add another in other layout. For some reason, when I created the second it changed the IDs of the first (one of them was 'title').

I deleted both ListViews but the problem persisted. So when I realized that I had the ListView with a 'title' id I decided to do it again with the first IDs and now everything works.

Couple of questions:

1. Why did the second ListView changed the first's IDs? - I created a Layout for the ListViews and seperate adapters since I wanted to show them in different ways.
2. Why deleting the layouts and the adapters did not solve the issue at first?

Plus, I still have an issue which is related. When I press the 3dots on the Toolbar (overflow), the app crashes. It throws a NullPointerException at ListMenuItemView. When I go to one of the faulty files in the question  it says that it `Cannot find the declaration of android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuItemView`... Any ideas on what's going  on?